# gateway sends packets (L3) without data link layer (L2) connection

Tags: networking, arp

pretty straightforward question:

```
#tcpdump -i wlp2s0 
[..]

16:33:37.328154 IP 185.29.43.134.https > achille.43692: Flags [FP.], seq 2980347197:2980347221, ack 988779763, win 63, options [nop,nop,TS val 4014285248 ecr 1087607705], length 24
16:33:42.345323 ARP, Request who-has achille tell _gateway, length 28
16:33:43.267564 ARP, Request who-has achille tell _gateway, length 28
16:33:44.291484 ARP, Request who-has achille tell _gateway, length 28
16:33:52.893459 IP 185.108.33.7.https > achille.33164: Flags [P.], seq 1790963150:1790965634, ack 3659102388, win 31, options [nop,nop,TS val 2212917620 ecr 1216687482], length 2484
16:33:52.893487 IP 185.108.33.7.https > achille.33164: Flags [P.], seq 2484:2515, ack 1, win 31, options [nop,nop,TS val 2212917620 ecr 1216687482], length 31
16:33:53.812781 ARP, Request who-has achille tell _gateway, length 28
```

at 16:33:42 my gateway (on my 3g router) looks unuable to contact my machine (achille) because I have flushed arp table, I keep flushing it so there is no updates sent to the gw. There is no routing to the gw neither (this should prevent my machine broadcasting arp requests?). So the gw is yelling through arp broadcasts but how could she send me 2 packets on port 443 at 16:33:52 (knowing that there is no complete data-link layer connection?

thanx folks!!

Answer (score 0):

The initial "Who-Has achille" ARP is sent to the broadcast address (`255.255.255.255`, anyone who hears this - it's for you). The packet also contains the 48 bit MAC address of the NIC sending the packet. The DHCP server replies using the MAC address, the reply packet goes to your NIC, done. Data Link Layer doesn't use "connections". Your ARP table contains the MAC address of the NICs you've recieved packets from, on the local Ethernet (L2).

Comment: .@waltinator: "Data Link Layer doesn't use "connections"; arp table maps MAC addresses with IPs. When this mapping is done, gateway can send packets to the machine whose mappings has been performed (in this sense, there is a  data link connection). In my case, although this mapping (MAC/IP) does not exist anymore, the gw still sends packets to my computer, why?